# clion wsl "CMake 3.20 or higher is required. You are running version 3.16.3"

Tags: cmake

so I just downloaded wslusing the wsl --install command using PowerShell
now I'm trying to connect it to Clion which works
[i cant add images so here is a link to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stywk.png)

but when i'm tying to build the project i get this error
"CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
CMake 3.20 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.16.3"

my cmake file:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(ex2 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(ex2
ex2.c ex2.h
main1.c
main2.c)

i tried updating wsl using wsl --update (in powershell)

Comment: From the image it is clearly that CLion uses `/usr/bin/cmake` which is of version 3.16.3. Obviously, this is lesser then 3.20 which is specified in `cmake_minimum_required`. And the error message tells exactly about that incompatibility. So, what is a **question**? Do you ask how to get CMake of newer version? For that you could try to find it in the package manager of the distro (probably, in Ubuntu). Or you could try to build CMake from sources.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Unfortunately the latest cmake version is rarely available via apt and WSL does not currently provide `snap` as an alternative. Compiling cmake yourself isn't necessary though, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CMake installation inside the WSL is used. Unfortunately currently snap doesn't seem to be available in WSL, but installing the latest CMake version isn't too complicated nonetheless:

1. (optional) uninstall the old cmake installation in WSL; personally I don't see any benefit in multiple CMake installations, but there may be valid reasons for this. Most likely this will just makes the use of cmake more complex, since you need to remember which cmake version is used.
2. Download the appropriate cmake version from the cmake website ( https://cmake.org/download/ ). The version to choose is the tar.gz file under binary distributions for the x86_64 target. To get version 3.21.4 (currently the latest release), you can download the file from https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.21.4/cmake-3.21.4-linux-x86_64.tar.gz (Identical to the link on the CMake download page).
3. Unpack the archive from WSL. Navigate to the directory where you want the cmake installation to recide. This will add the cmake-3.21.4-linux-x86_64 directory containing all the files required to work with cmake to the current working directory. Let's assume you want to add the cmake files to the `/opt` directory. Furthermore let's assume the windows user name to be `fabian`, `C:` to be the primary hard drive and the download to be saved to the `Downloads` directory in the user directory:

   ```
    cd /opt
    tar -xf /mnt/c/Users/fabian/Downloads/cmake-3.21.4-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
4. (optional) make CMake available without specifying the path; this could be done as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere ; don't do this, if an existing cmake installation is already available in the command line assuming you did install cmake to `/opt`, the cmake binary recides at `/opt/cmake-3.21.4-linux-x86_64/bin`

You should now be able to use cmake specifying either the full path to the executable (`/opt/cmake-3.21.4-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake` assuming you used the `/opt` directory) or directly via a command after opening the WLS commandline again (provided you followed step 4).

Now the only thing left to do should be telling CLion about the location of the cmake executable. Note that I haven't tested this, since I don't use this IDE. It's working fine using Visual Studio Code though...

Comment: thanks a lot for the well written guide it worked.
I did a few (minor) things so I will just write it here for those who look this post in the future:
1. Clion (currently) support up to cmake 3.20 so just download this version and did the same as in the guide.
2. also needed to download compiler and make using this command -> "sudo apt-get install build-essential gdb".